# Do not return all values when SSRS wildcard search is blank

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

How can a SSRS wildcard search be stopped from returning all values when left blank? Currently, if I enter a value for SKU (generated by the script below) and don't enter at least one value for SKU_Description the report returns all records rather than just the SKU record.

I have parameters set to allow blanks and multiple values because I need the ability to enter either an SKU or an SKU_Description or both, depending on what is know about each product.

```
WHERE A.sku in (@SKU) 
OR B.sku_desc like '%' + @SKU_Description + '%'
```

I thought something like this might work, but it doesn't:

```
IIf(Parameters!SKU_Description.Value="",  "WHERE A.sku in (@SKU)"
, "WHERE A.sku in (@SKU) or B.sku_desc like '%' + @SKU_Description + '%'")
```

Every thread I can find is about returning all values when left blank, which is the opposite of what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

your query might need to look like this instead.

```
WHERE (@SKU = '' OR A.sku in (@SKU)) 
AND (@SKU_Description = '' OR B.sku_desc like '%' + @SKU_Description + '%')
```

if @SKU or @SKU_Description can be NULL then you'll probably want

```
WHERE (ISNULL(@SKU,'') = '' OR A.sku in (@SKU)) 
AND (ISNULL(@SKU_Description,'') = '' OR B.sku_desc like '%' + @SKU_Description + '%')
```

**Edit:**

you can use this if the Sku and SKU_Description dont have to match for same record.

```
WHERE A.sku in (@SKU) 
OR (@SKU_Description <> '' AND B.sku_desc like '%' + @SKU_Description + '%')
```

Comment: Thank you, very close! But, this solution works only for one product at a time. I need a solution that accommodates multiple values that can be referenced by either SKU or SKU_Description simultaneously. For example, if known, SKUs will be entered. But, an SKU should also be able to be entered at the same time as a SKU_Description on another product whose SKU is not known. This almost works in my original query, except when SKUs are entered and the SKU_Description is left blank all all values in are returned because the wildcard search is matching everything - instead of being ignored.

Comment: @AnDrEw I gotcha..   maybe the Edit is what you need instead